# How to use variable in reusable block in Play Framework 2 (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I can't find the way how to interpolate variable in reusable block.
I've tried this without luck:

```
@headers = @{
    page match {
        case "home" => Map(
                "title" -> "Welcome",
                "description" -> "Welcome to our site")
        case "profile" => Map(
                "title" -> "@user.name - @site.name",
                "description" -> "Hello @user.name")
        }
    }


@headers = @{
    page match {
        case "home" => Map(
            "title" -> "Welcome",
            "description" -> "Welcome to our site")
        case "profile" => Map(
            "title" -> user.name + "-" site.name,
            "description" -> "Hello" + user.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the normal [Scala string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html). Like `s"Hello ${user.name}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your variables as parameter:

```
@headers(user:User,site:Site) = @{
    page match {
        case "home" => Map(
            "title" -> "Welcome",
            "description" -> "Welcome to our site")
        case "profile" => Map(
            "title" -> user.name + "-" site.name,
            "description" -> "Hello" + user.name)
    }
}
```

Note: I guessed what type `user` and `site` had. You need to changes those of course.

Have a look at the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTemplates#Declaring-reusable-blocks

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. Is it possible to convert this code to separate view file?

Comment: Yes you can. It works like the "main-view" in the example project. Have a look here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases